Route "src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts" does not match the required types of a Next.js Route. "authOptions" is not a valid Route export fie
I am having this problem when deploying my site in Vercel, in localhsot it works excellent.enter image description here
I also tried separating authOptions into an auth.ts component but it didn't work either and gave me this error
enter image description here
Currently this is how my route.ts is: src\app\api\auth[...nextauth]
import { SupabaseAdapter } from "@auth/supabase-adapter";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";
import { getUserData, signInEmailPassword } from '../../../../../lib/next-auth/actions';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: SupabaseAdapter({
      url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
      secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY!,
    }) as Adapter,
    providers: [
      GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_ID!,
        clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET!,
      }),
  
      CredentialsProvider({
        name: "Credentials",
        credentials: {
          email: { label: "Correo electrónico", type: "email", placeholder: "usuario@gmail.com" },
          password: { label: "Contraseña", type: "password", placeholder: '******' }
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
          const user = await signInEmailPassword(credentials!.email, credentials!.password)
  
          if (user) {
            return user;
          }
          return null;
        }
      }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  
    session: {
      strategy: 'jwt',
    },
  
    callbacks: {
      async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
        return true;
      },
      async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
        const dbUser = await getUserData(token.email);
  
        token.rol = dbUser?.rol ?? 'no-rol';
        token.id = dbUser?.id ?? 'no-uuid';
        return token;
      },
  
      async session({ session, token, user }) {
        if (session && session.user) {
          session.user.rol = token.rol;
          session.user.id = token.id;
        }
        return session;
      },
    },
  };


const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }


This question is similar to: authOptions is not a valid Route export field. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

just had the same issue and I solved it by moving authOptions into a seperate file '@/app/utils/authOptions.ts'.
Now the route.ts file should look like:
import { authOptions } from "@/app/utils/authOptions";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


You have literally beaten ChatGPT plus, you are a beast bro, Stack Overflow is not dead (yet).
